# How to HyperLink block_name on any block or Product Slider Name Title

Tags: blocks, cms-block, link, slider, name

When using the code below, it shows feature product slider on any CMS page with the title that is a value of the `block_name` attribute.

It's shown as a plain text, but I want to make it a hyperlink.

In other words, how to make the title of a slider block into a link, which is clickable?

```
{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" 
template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml"
timeout="4000" loop="1" category_id="655" product_count="12" 
hide_button="1" timeout="16000" is_random="1"  block_name="Clearance Sale"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the goal you have to change template `catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml` (or provide another template) for the block to render a link instead of a title.
This is not achievable from the admin panel and requires development.

If you'd like to avoid development, the hack I can think about is adding javascript to the pages where block is rendered (can be done using CMS Block/Widget) that will wrap a title with a link html tag. The javascript required will depend on block contents.

Comment: [link](http://prnt.sc/ekungq) , here is the example of the featured block, will highly appreciate if i could get any workable solution.  :) little explanation will help alot, thanks for the answer though @sergey